# Stylelint: Undefined rule font-family-no-missing-generic-family-keyword

Tags: css, webpack, postcss, stylelint

It happens when I run stylefmt and stylefmt-loader through webpack with stylelint-config-recommend

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`font-family-no-missing-generic-family-keyword` was added in `stylelint` 8.3.0; if you are using the latest version of `stylelint-config-recommended` you will need to update your version of `stylelint` to 8.3.x to match.

If `stylefmt` installs its own `stylelint` you could override the subdependency with e.g. `yarn`'s support for that or downgrade your version of `stylelint-config-recommended`.

Answer (score 1):

stylefmt (the latest released to the moment is 6.0) uses a previous version of stylelint. In that version, that rule does not exist.

Here is the issue reported to stylefmt: https://github.com/morishitter/stylefmt/issues/334

If you are using Yarn you can force that dependency to 8.3.0 and you will fix the issue. To force it, you need to add a resolutions property in the package.json and specify the stylelint version:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "stylelint": "8.3.0"
  }
```